# Wifi connection slow on Mac only

Tags: network, wifi

My iMac (Ver 10.9.5 for reasons, iMac is from 2012) has an observed download speed of ~100KBps. On speedtest.net, it tells me the speed is ~800Kbps, so it matches up. However, on other devices, the download speed is way higher, about 35Mbps.

The modem is an Asus, RT-N66U. The router is an ARRIS surfboard SB6141.

The connection is wireless.

The RSSI is -47, MCS index is 23, Noise is -88, speed is 217Mbps, Phy mode is 802.11n. The country code is US.

Could anyone help fix the slow connection on this Mac?

Answer (score 2):

This was extremely fast, but I was fiddling with the wifi settings, and I noticed the ASUS traffic manager was enabled. Upon disabling it, I had the same download speed as other devices. It had limited my own device for whatever reason.